# Why in Objective-C and iOS, [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] gave warning but NSMutableArray.new didn't?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a property for my `MainView` class, `arr`

```
@property NSMutableArray *arr;
```

In my `ViewController.m`, inside `viewDidLoad`, if I use

```
MainView *mainView = (MainView *) self.view;
mainView.arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

It compiled, but gave a warning of "Assigning retained object to unsafe property; object will be released after assignment".  But if I change the second line above to

```
mainView.arr = NSMutableArray.new;
```

then there will be no warning.  I thought `alloc init` is the same as `new`?  Why does the first version give warning and actually is it dangerous or can it be made so there is no warning?

Comment: What version of Xcode is this?

Comment: Xcode 4.3.2.. the current one

Answer (score 2):

If you use `[NSMutableArray new]` syntax, you will see the warning, so it's not an issue that your problem went away, but rather that your nonstandard syntax of `NSMutableArray.new` didn't generate the warning. The problem is that your property is defaulting to an unsafe_unretained, and whenever you assign a retained object to the unsafe_unretained object, ARC will immediately release it for you. Just try adding an object to your array and then NSLog'ing it, and you'll see the EXC_BAD_ACCESS which illustrates the problem. Change your property to:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arr;
```

and your problem goes away.

Again, the lack of warning from your nonstandard usage of `NSMutableArray.new` is not an indication that there's no problem, but rather that the compiler just didn't generate the warning for you. (Frankly, I'm really surprised that the dot syntax for invoking a method worked at all. The dot notation is generally used for accessing properties, not for invoking methods.) Use the `[NSMutableArray new]` syntax if you really want to use `new`. But the preferred syntax is really `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`.

Heed the warnings.

Comment: interesting... even with the warning, I could access the array and addObject to the array without any problem... it can be 3 minutes later that an object is added to the array and it is still ok...

Comment: Are you using ARC? The behavior I describe is relevant to ARC code. If not, you'll want to use @Nikolai's retain syntax, which eliminates the warning. But regardless, you don't want to leave the code without the attributes for your property.

Comment: On my ARC project, I was able to add a string to the array, but when I did the `NSLog(@"%@", mainView.arr)`, I got the EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: Using ARC is great. (I'm never going back!) I dunno why you're not seeing the behavior I describe, but regardless, you really want to then declare it as strong if your object owns to prevent the possibility of the sort of problem I describe. The compiler is quite right re its warning.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the reason you're getting the warning is because arr is not a strong reference. If you try "@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arr;", the warning will go away.

P.S. "(strong, nonatomic)" is the approach to use when employing automatic reference counting (ARC). I too am surprised that NSMutableArray.new worked. I think it's better to use "[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]". That way, Xcode will tell you if the class you are instantiating has a more appropriate, specialty initializer (e.g. "initWithFrame:").

Comment: both `(strong, nonatomic)` and `(retain)` made the warning go away and the program ran fine... I just don't know which version is more standard or more common usage?

Comment: +new is documented to do the same as +alloc/-init, so it's the lack of compiler warning that's the bug.

Answer (score 1):

You must tell type of property. For example:

```
@property (retain) NSMutableArray *arr;
```

See *property type* in documentation.

Comment: both `(strong, nonatomic)` and `(retain)` made the warning go away and the program ran fine... I just don't know which version is more standard or more common usage?

Comment: Use strong for ARC, retain for non ARC.

Comment: nonatomic the faster way. In iOS use (strong, nonatomic), on the mac (retain).

Comment: @NikolaiNagorny, nonatomic is faster, so your correct to say to use it, but if there is threading involved use atomic. But you should use strong if using ARC, and retain if your not. That is independent of iOS/Mac.